# Additional data in the comments

Tags: comments

Need to add to comments selection of Like/Dislike. The form of adding text requires a mandatory choice of one of two options. In the form of a radio button. And, accordingly, display this field for published comments. Sorting no need.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you update your question to indicate which version of EE you are using please?

Comment: I have EE 1, 3 and 5. :)

Comment: Do you want to get the feature of the like and dislike the comments ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it very simply. You can use a ready-made {location} field and a radio button with options. The radio sends 1 (Like) or 2 (Dislike) to the {location} filed.

Only does not work with registered users. For them, the {location} field is already filled in, even if it is empty.